# What is the correct way to write dissociation reactions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, equilibrium, solubility

The variants are as follows:

For a salt (NaCl):

$$\ce{NaCl_{(s)}<=>NaCl_{(aq)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{1}$$

$$\ce{NaCl_{(s)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{2}$$

$$\ce{NaCl_{(aq)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{3}$$

$$\ce{NaCl_{(s)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>NaCl_{(aq)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-} + H_2O_{(l)}}\tag{4}$$

$$\ce{NaCl_{(s)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-} + H_2O_{(l)}}\tag{5}$$

$$\ce{NaCl_{(aq)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-} + H_2O_{(l)}}\tag{6}$$

$$\ce{NaCl_{(s)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{7}$$

$$\ce{NaCl_{(aq)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{8}$$

Which of these are right/wrong and why?

Comment: I am afraid you are overthinking about notation. The only problem is that the plus and minus are too far off from the elemental symbol. An chemical equation cannot describe every process. It is just a shorthand notation. You will still need words to explain what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am showing the different versions of the equation followed by my comments.

> $$\ce{NaCl_{(s)}<=>NaCl_{(aq)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{1}$$

$\ce{NaCl_{(aq)}}$ is the same as $\ce{Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}$ so it makes no sense to show them in equilibrium.

> $$\ce{NaCl_{(s)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{2}$$

This would be my preference. The physical state is written more conventionally after the charge of the ion, and not as a subscript:

$$\ce{NaCl(s)<=>Na+(aq) + Cl-(aq)}\tag{2a}$$

> $$\ce{NaCl_{(aq)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{3}$$

See (1).

> $$\ce{NaCl_{(s)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>NaCl_{(aq)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-} + H_2O_{(l)}}\tag{4}$$

There is no reason to show a single water molecule. This would suggest a 1:1 stoichiometry but there are multiple water molecules in the solvation shells of the two ions.

> $$\ce{NaCl_{(s)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-} + H_2O_{(l)}}\tag{5}$$

See (4).

> $$\ce{NaCl_{(aq)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-} + H_2O_{(l)}}\tag{6}$$

See (4).

> $$\ce{NaCl_{(s)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{7}$$

This one is not balanced.

> $$\ce{NaCl_{(aq)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>Na_{(aq)}^{+} + Cl_{(aq)}^{-}}\tag{8}$$

See (7).

> Which of these are right/wrong and why?

Some of them are not balanced, and some, while balanced, are not describing the process as accurately and succinctly as version (2).

Comment: I agree completely.

Comment: @user545735 either one is fine. (1) shows an H+ transfer from acetic acid to water (Bronsted acid/base). (2) saves some keystrokes and shows the water implicitly.

Comment: @user545735 Yes because there are more than one water molecule involved in hydrating or salvation the hydrogen ion.